# Arguments inside "onChange" its no compatble with "NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputChangeEventData>"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am new with react native and when i try do this

```
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChange={(text) => setPontoValue(text)}
        />
```

i receive this error

`TS2345: Argument of type 'NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputChangeEventData>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<undefined>'.   Type 'NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputChangeEventData>' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: undefined): undefined'.`

all code is below

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import {
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  View, Button,
} from 'react-native'


export default function App() {
  const [pontoValue, setPontoValue] = useState()
  const [dataValue, setDataValue] = useState()

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.repositoryContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChange={(text) => setPontoValue(text)}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          value={dataValue}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Button
            title="Calcular"
            onPress={teste}>Converter
          </Button>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )

  function teste() {
    if (pontoValue) {
      setDataValue(pontoValue.replace(/[ .]+/g, ''))
    }
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#7199c1',
  },
  repositoryContainer: {
    marginBottom: 15,
    marginHorizontal: 15,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding: 20,
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    padding: 5,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  buttonText: {
    marginVertical: 11,
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#fff',
    backgroundColor: '#7159c1',
    padding: 15,
  },
})
```

Comment: (text) => {setPontoValue(text)}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`onChange` event returns an event object which has `nativeEvent` function which providers access to the following properties: `{ eventCount, target, text}`

you need the `text` property, so you can use:

```js
onChange={(event) => setPontoValue(event.nativeEvent.text)}
```

or

```js
onChangeText={(text) => setPontoValue(text)}
```

Comment: Kindly format your answer with the provided formatting tools. Makes your answer easier to read and understand

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use `onChangeText` prop.

`onChangeText` is a prop that gives you only text changes.

`onChange` on the other hand, passes an event.

So, try this

```
<TextInput
  style={styles.input}
  onChangeText={(text) => setPontoValue(text)}
/>
```

Also, always initialize your state variables.

```
const [pontoValue, setPontoValue] = useState('')
const [dataValue, setDataValue] = useState('')
```

It will reduce to chance of getting `undefined` errors.

Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

`onChange` returns a nativeEvent object that has the `text` (string type) property that you need to set your state.
To resolve the problem, you have two options:

1. Keep the current `onChange` prop and access the text property from nativeEvent

```
<TextInput
   style={styles.input}
   onChange={(event) => setPontoValue(event.nativeEvent.text)}
/>
```

2. Use `onChangeText` prop

```
<TextInput
   style={styles.input}
   onChangeText={(text) => setPontoValue(text)}
/>
```

Either way should work